# i got this error on runtime when i tried to get nearst place

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, geolocation

while i trying to get nearest place using entity frame work i got this error on run time

note: my latitude and longitude data type in my sql db is float and i mapped it to double in my entity model

```
public JsonResult GetNearstCity(double latitude,double longitude)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var coord = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);
        var nearest = db.Cities.Select(x => new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude,x.Longtiude))
                               .OrderBy(x => x.GetDistanceTo(coord))
                               .First();
        return Json(nearest, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

'Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.'
```

Answer (score 1):

EF wants to translate or track everything in the Linq expression to SQL. SQL has no notion of what a GeoCoordinate object is, so EF cannot construct one using parameters. You can tell EF to construct an object with a default constructor since EF will request the fields from the applicable tables and then set the properties once the query is executed.

For instance, this would work:

```
var nearest = db.Cities.Select(x => new GeoCoordinate 
    {
        Latitude = x.Latitude,
        Longitude = x.Longitude
    });
```

This requires that Latitude and Longitude are public properties on your GeoCoordinate.

The next problem you will face is that you won't be able to call `GetDistanceTo(coord)` inside the linq expression either. Again, EF will not be able to send this method to SQL since SQL will not know what this method is.  There are two option available here:

Option 1: If the amount of data is reasonable, you can have EF execute the overall query for all cities, then from that point you are dealing with Linq2Object, not Linq2EF so you can call a class function on GeoCoordinate:

```
var nearest = db.Cities.Select(x => new GeoCoordinate 
    {
        Latitude = x.Latitude,
        Longitude = x.Longitude
    }).ToList()
    .OrderBy(x => x.GetDistanceTo(coord))
    .First();
```

By calling `.ToList()` EF will execute our query to return all Cities. From there you can use functions on your class for further calculations. The downside of this approach is that you will be loading all cities into memory. If you have a large amount of data this will be prohibitive for performance and resources.

Option 2: Translate the method into something SQL will understand. This option allows EF to translate your calculation into something SQL can execute, which does the work at the DB side and then only returns the single record you want. Rather than having the logic in a method on the GeoCoordinate entity, you do the calculation inside the Linq expression. Something like:

```
var nearest = db.Cities.Select(x => new GeoCoordinate 
    {
        Latitude = x.Latitude,
        Longitude = x.Longitude
    })
    .OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x.Latitude - coord.Latitude) + Math.Abs(x.Longitude - coord.Longitude))
    .First();
```

This is likely *not* the formula you want to apply to find the closest 2 points, it is merely an example of a similar formula. `Math.Abs()` is a .Net method, however EF does know how to translate that to SQL. Take the logic you have inside your entity for that `GetDistanceTo(coord)` method and move it up into the Linq expression and you should be pretty much there.

Answer (score 0):

The error is exactly what it says: you need to create a class GeoCoordinate with a parameterless constructor and properties to set the Latitude and Longitude:

```
class GeoCoordinate
{
    public int Latitude {get; set;}
    public int Longitude {get; set;}

    ... // other properties and methods
}

var result = dbContext.Cities
    .Select(city => new GeoCoordinate
    {
        Latitude = city.Latitude,
        Longitude = city.Longitude
    })
    .OrderBy(coordinate => coordinate.GetDistanceTo(coord))
    .First();
```

By the way, your database management system does not know function GetDistanceTo, so if you want to let your DBMS do the complete querye (AsQueryable) do the following:

```
GeoCoordinate coord = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);
var result = dbContext.Cities
    .Select(city => new
    {
        Latitude = city.Latitude,
        Longitude = city.Longitude
        Distance = sqrt (coord.Latitude * coord.Latitude + coord.Longitude * coord.Longitude),
    })
    .OrderBy(coordinates => coordinates.Distance)
    .Select(coordinates => new GeoCoordinate
    {
        Latitude = coordinates.Latitude,
        Longitude = coordinates.Longitude,
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```